# Does there exist something like (xs:x)

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell. I know I can create a `reverse` function by doing this:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse [] = []
reverse (x:xs) = (Main.reverse xs) ++ [x]
```

Is there such a thing as `(xs:x)` (a list concatenated with an element, i.e. `x` is the last element in the list) so that I put the last list element at the front of the list?

```
rotate :: [a] -> [a]
rotate [] = []
rotate (xs:x) = [x] ++ xs
```

I get these errors when I try to compile a program containing this function:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = [a]
When generalising the type(s) for `rotate'
```

Comment: If you need the tail of the list then you're using the wrong data structure for your problem.  Consider a tree, dlist, sequence or other structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm also new to Haskell, so my answer is not authoritative. Anyway, I would do it using `last` and `init`:

```
Prelude> last [1..10] : init [1..10]
[10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

or

```
Prelude> [ last [1..10] ] ++ init [1..10]
[10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is: this is not possible with pattern matching, you have to use a function.

The long answer is: it's not in standard Haskell, but it is if you are willing to use an extension called View Patterns, and also if you have no problem with your pattern matching eventually taking longer than constant time.

The reason is that pattern matching is based on how the structure is constructed in the first place. A list is an abstract type, which have the following structure:

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
           deriving (Show) -- this is just so you can print the List
```

When you declare a type like that you generate three objects: a type constructor `List`, and two data constructors: `Empty` and `Cons`. The type constructor takes types and turns them into other types, i.e., `List` takes a type `a` and creates another type `List a`. The data constructor works like a function that returns something of type `List a`. In this case you have:

```
Empty :: List a
```

representing an empty list and

```
Cons :: a -> List a -> List a
```

which takes a value of type `a` and a list and appends the value to the head of the list, returning another list. So you can build your lists like this:

```
empty = Empty         -- similar to []
list1 = Cons 1 Empty  -- similar to 1:[] = [1]
list2 = Cons 2 list1  -- similar to 2:(1:[]) = 2:[1] = [2,1]
```

This is more or less how lists work, but in the place of `Empty` you have `[]` and in the place of `Cons` you have `(:)`. When you type something like `[1,2,3]` this is just syntactic sugar for `1:2:3:[]` or `Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Empty))`.

When you do pattern matching, you are "de-constructing" the type. Having knowledge of how the type is structured allows you to uniquely disassemble it. Consider the function:

```
head :: List a -> a
head (Empty) = error " the empty list have no head"
head (Cons x xs) = x
```

What happens on the type matching is that the data constructor is matched to some structure you give. If it matches `Empty`, than you have an empty list. If if matches `Const x xs` then `x` must have type `a` and must be the head of the list and `xs` must have type `List a` and be the tail of the list, cause that's the type of the data constructor:

```
Cons  :: a -> List a -> List a
```

If `Cons x xs` is of type `List a` than `x` must be `a` and `xs`  must be `List a`. The same is true for (x:xs). If you look to the type of (:) in GHCi:

```
> :t (:) 
 (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So, if (x:xs) is of type `[a]`, `x` must be `a` and `xs` must be `[a]` . The error message you get when you try to do `(xs:x)` and then treat `xs` like a list, is exactly because of this. By your use of `(:)` the compiler infers that `xs` have type `a`, and by your use of 
`++`, it infers that `xs` must be `[a]`. Then it freaks out cause there's no finite type `a` for which `a = [a]` - this is what he's trying to tell you with that error message.

If you need to disassemble the structure in other ways that don't match the way the data constructor builds the structure, than you have to write your own function. There are two functions in the standard library that do what you want: `last` returns the last element of a list, and `init` returns all-but-the-last elements of the list.

But note that pattern matching happens in constant time. To find out the head and  the tail of a list, it doesn't matter how long the list is, you just have to look to the outermost data constructor. Finding the last element is `O(N)`: you have to dig until you find the innermost `Cons` or the innermost `(:)`, and this requires you to "peel" the structure N times, where N is the size of the list.

If you frequently have to look for the last element in long lists, you might consider if using a list is a good idea after all. You can go after `Data.Sequence` (constant time access to first and last elements), `Data.Map` (`log(N)` time access to any element if you know its key), `Data.Array` (constant time access to an element if you know its index), `Data.Vector` or other data structures that match your needs better than lists.

Ok. That was the short answer (:P). The long one you'll have to lookup a bit by yourself, but here's an intro.

You can have this working with a syntax very close to pattern matching by using view patterns. View Patterns are an extension that you can use by having this as the first line of your code:

```
{-# Language ViewPatterns #-}
```

The instructions of how to use it are here: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns

With view patterns you could do something like:

```
view :: [a] -> (a, [a])
view xs = (last xs, init xs)

someFunction :: [a] -> ...
someFunction (view -> (x,xs)) = ...
```

than `x` and `xs` will be bound to the `last` and the `init` of the list you provide to `someFunction`. Syntactically it feels like pattern matching, but it is really just applying `last` and `init` to the given list.

Answer (score 7):

If you're willing to use something different from plain lists, you could have a look at the `Seq` type in the containers package, as documented [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html). This has O(1) cons (element at the front) and snoc (element at the back), and allows pattern matching the element from the front and the back, through use of Views.

Answer (score 4):

"Is there such a thing as (xs:x) (a list concatenated with an element, i.e. x is the last element in the list) so that I put the last list element at the front of the list?"

No, not in the sense that you mean.  These "patterns" on the left-hand side of a function definition are a reflection of how a data structure is defined by the programmer and stored in memory.  Haskell's built-in list implementation is a singly-linked list, ordered from the beginning - so the pattern available for function definitions reflects exactly that, exposing the very first element plus the rest of the list (or alternatively, the empty list).

For a list constructed in this way, the last element is not immediately available as one of the stored components of the list's top-most node.  So instead of that value being present in pattern on the left-hand side of the function definition, it's calculated by the function body onthe right-hand side.

Of course, you can define new data structures, so if you want a new list that makes the last element available through pattern-matching, you could build that.  But there's be some cost:  Maybe you'd just be storing the list backwards, so that it's now the first element which is not available by pattern matching, and requires computation.  Maybe you're storing both the first and last value in the structures, which would require additional storage space and bookkeeping.

It's perfectly reasonable to think about multiple implementations of a single data structure concept - to look forward a little bit, this is one use of Haskell's class/instance definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing as you suggested might be much less efficient. Last is not O(1) operation, but is O(N) and that mean that rotating as you suggested becomes O(N^2) alghorhim.

Source:
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/src/GHC-List.html#last

<strike>Your first version has O(n) complexity.</strike> Well it is not, becuase ++ is also O(N) operation

you should do this like

```
rotate l =  rev l []
   where
      rev []     a = a
      rev (x:xs) a = rev xs (x:a)
```

source : http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/src/GHC-List.html#reverse

Comment: Your `rotate` is not rotation.

Answer (score 0):

In your latter example, `x` is in fact a list.  `[x]` becomes a list of lists, e.g. `[[1,2], [3,4]]`.

`(++)` wants a list of the same type on both sides.  When you are using it, you're doing `[[a]] ++ [a]` which is why the compiler is complaining.  According to your code `a` would be the same type as `[a]`, which is impossible.

In `(x:xs)`, `x` is the first item of the list (the head) and `xs` is everything but the head, i.e., the tail.  The names are irrelevant here, you might as well call them `(head:tail)`.

If you really want to take the last item of the input list and put that in the front of the result list, you could do something like:

```
rotate :: [a] -> [a]
rotate [] = []
rotate lst = (last lst):(rotate $ init lst)
```

N.B. I haven't tested this code at all as I don't have a Haskell environment available at the moment.

Comment: (last lst):(rotate lst) becomes longer and longer since you do not remove last element.
http://ideone.com/ix6yb

Comment: You can try it yourself on that page. Just hit clone, edit source and hit submit. And by the way, yes this fixes bug.

Comment: NB: you can simplify the last line by eliding spurious parentheses `rotate lst = last lst : rotate (init lst)`